# Dynamically Create Object with For Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, loops

I am trying to iterate (with a for..in loop) multiple entries and output them as a json object. Where I am running into difficulty is that the data only outputs a single list entry, and not all of them. Using AxiosJS in Node, I've found it outputs in the exact format I'd like. I'm unsure how to format my loop in order to output like this:

```
{
  "Cardio_ETC": {
    "name": "John",
    "shift": "7a-7a",
    "service": "ETC Cardiology",
    "Office": "1234",
    "cell": ""
  },
  "Cardio_STEMI": {
    "name": "Pran",
    "shift": "7a-7a",
    "service": "STEMI Cardiology",
    "Office": "34561321",
    "cell": ""
  },
  "fastTrack1": {
    "name": "Bob",
    "shift": "7a-7p",
    "service": "Fasttrack",
    "Office": "X533 tel",
    "cell": "X533"
  },...etc
```

Here is my current code:

```
.then((data)=>{
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM amion_onCall", function (err, result, fields){
            //format results here

                var fixed = new Object();

                let i;
                for (i in result){
                    aName = result[i].name;
                    serv = result[i].specialty;
                    aServ = serv.replace(' ','_');
                    aShift = result[i].shift;
                    aOff = result[i].office;
                    aCell = result[i].cell;
                    aTag  = result[i].tag;


var data = {name:aName, service: aServ, shift: aShift, office: aOff, cell: aCell, tag: aTag};

            Object.assign(fixed, data);
            console.log(fixed);
```

What is the best way to format this for..in loop in order to output the above json?

Comment: Please Upvote my question if you can, I don't have enough reputation in order to upvote your answers (I'm new)!

Comment: I did not understand anything. what result do you want from which source? why add an SQL query to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, If you want to use for in you can do this

```js
const obj = {};
for (i in result) {
  obj[result[i].tag] = {
    name: result[i].name,
    service: result[i].specialty.replace(' ', '_'),
    shift: result[i].shift,
    office: result[i].office,
    cell: result[i].cell,
  }
}
console.log(obj) // will have your answer
```

but I recommend using reduce

```js
.then((data) => {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM amion_onCall",
    function (err, result) {

      const obj = result.reduce((o, item) => {
        o[item.tag] = {
          name: item.name,
          service: item.specialty.replace(' ', '_'),
          shift: item.shift,
          office: item.office,
          cell: item.cell,
        }
        return o
      }, {});

      console.log(obj)
    })
})
```